# asp.net css inline formatting

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm using 2 menus with a label above each. I'm trying to align them side by side however I'm having trouble. It is acting as if there is a `<br/>` in between `#MenuFooter1` and `#MenuFooter2`.Notice I'm using a `<br/>` after the labels. Current result:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMi0e.png

```
<div id="footer">
     <div class="MenuFooter1"> 
     <asp:Label ID="lblAdvantages" runat="server" Text="Advantages" ForeColor="#ab2548" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br />

      <telerik:RadMenu ID="MenuFooter1" runat="server" OnClientItemClicked="MenuNavBar_ItemClicked" Skin="Transparent" Flow="Vertical" >
        <Items>                 
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Why ?" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>              
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="View the Data" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>              
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Advocates" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>

        </Items>
    </telerik:RadMenu>
    </div>
    <div class="MenuFooter2" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Advantages" ForeColor="#ab2548" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br />
     <telerik:RadMenu ID="MenuFooter2" runat="server" OnClientItemClicked="MenuNavBar_ItemClicked" Skin="Transparent" Flow="Vertical" style="top: 0px; left: 0px">
        <Items>                 
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Why?" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>              
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="View the Data" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>              
            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Advocates" NavigateUrl="http://" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#999999" Font-Names="Arial">
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>

        </Items>
    </telerik:RadMenu>
     </div> 
    </div>
```

css

```
#footer {
        padding:80px;
        display:inline;
        }

     .MenuFooter1, .MenuFooter2 {
        display:block;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `block` to `inline-block`

```
 #MenuFooter1, #MenuFooter2 {
        display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like it should. I think I tried that at one point however I found my problem was that I referred my MenuFooter classes as ID's in the css. smh

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Wasn't able to accept so quickly yesterday.